# Sass mixin color-name compiling issue

Tags: colors, compilation, sass

I've just wrote a mixin supposed to display an @2x icon version for retina display.

First, here is an example of an icon name :

```
      images/icon/close-black.png
      images/icon/close-black@2x.png
```

Here is the mixin :

```
     @mixin background-image-retina($type, $file, $color, $ext) {
           background-image: url('src/assets/images/' + $type + '/' + $file + '-' + $color + '.' + $ext);
           @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
              only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
              only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
              only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
              only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi),
              only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx){
              & {
                  background-image: url('src/assets/images/' + $type + '/' + $file + '-' + $color + '@2x.' + $type);
              }
           }                                                                          
      }
```

So I call my mixin :

```
    @include background-image-retina(icon, close, black, png);
```

And here the result, and here is the problem :

```
    background-image: url(src/assets/images/icon/close-#000.png);
```

My question :

**Does anyone know how to specify the icon color without compiling it in an actual HEX color?**

Thanks for your help!

A/W

---

**[EDIT: SOLUTION FOUND]**

To avoid color-like names compilation in your mixin, just add quotation marks around it.

```
      black    ->    #000
      "black"  ->    black
```

Comment: Okay, I think I've just found the solution. So simple by the way...

To avoid color-like names compilation in your mixin,**just add quotation marks around it**. I will edit my question to whom needs the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have an old version of SASS. Surrounding colors in strings is fine, but it's unnecessary. Also if you interpolate the value, even in older versions, I think it will fix your issue; plus it's shorter and easier to follow. I made you a [sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/2d65c178994b373f5ebb776142148783) with both; comparing interpolated and non-interpolated variables in a newer version of SASS. But here's basically what I'm saying:

```
@mixin background-image-retina($type, $file, $color, $ext) {
  background-image: url('src/assets/images/#{$type}/#{$file}-#{$color}.#{$ext}');

  @media only screen and (whatevs) {
      & {
          background-image: url('src/assets/images/#{$type}/#{$file}-#{$color}@2x.#{$type}');
      }
  }                                                                          
}

.hey { @include background-image-retina(icon, close, black, png); }
```